# Is there a difference in how named pipes work between python 2 and python 3 in Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, named-pipes

I have a simple exe file that creates named pipes for communication with a virtual comm port.  A Python application communicates with the named ports and the exe then communicates with the VCP (think of the exe as a pair of deep FIFOs in front of the VCP).  The exe runs in a separate process and is used to provide large buffers and for better performance than doing this in Python.  It just runs continuously until stopped (by a mutex) passing data between a Python application and the VCP. It has been used for years, first with Windows 7 and Python 2.7 and then with Windows 10 and Python 2.7.  But when I switch to Python 3 (using Win10), I can no longer communicate with the named pipes.

I created a Python program (call it PythonEXE for short) that duplicates the functionality of the exe, runs in a separate process (opened with popen), and it works in Python3.  So I know the named pipes are working in Python 3 and that it's not some kind of issue with using separate processes (which the application does all over the place, so I'd have other issues if that were happening).

I know the named pipes are being sent bytes (not string characters) by the Python 3 application because, first, I don’t get any exceptions when communicating with them, and because it works with the PythonEXE program that duplicates the functionality of the original exe. It’s not an OS issue because the same exe works with both Win7 and Win10, as long as I’m using Pythion 2.7.

The exe doesn’t crash, it works until it is told to shut down, which it does gracefully. I’ve tried opening it with os.startfile and with popen, both methods give the same result.

I know the first question someone will ask is for code snippets, which I can provide, but my initial question is very simple: **Does anyone know of a change between Python 2.7 and Python 3 (using 3.8.8 at the moment) that would explain this behavior?**  Anything different in the way named pipes work in Windows between the two Python versions?  I’m stumped at the moment.  I can see that I’m sending the right things but it just doesn’t work the same between Python 2 and Python 3.  Same OS, same EXE, no crashes, no errors, it’s just like things sent to the named pipes are going into a black hole. Since it works with python-to-python named pipes (one end being in PythonEXE), the difference has to be in the way Python 3 communicates with named pipes created in the original exe (as opposed to communicating with named pipes created by PythonEXE).

Just FYI: I have the source for the exe, but not the development environment (it’s years old).  Before going down the path of re-creating that for debug, I want to make sure there isn’t some change to Python between versions 2 and 3 that would explain this and that might be easy to fix.

Yes, I might be able to just use the PythonEXE, but I’ll have to do a lot of testing to be sure there aren’t performance issues; I want to use the existing EXE because that’s all been tested and I know it works.

I appreciate anyone who can say "oh, yes, I know what this is, you need to....."

Well, OK, if you want code, I created a debug program to work on this issue, it's stripped of all the extra code to run the HW and other SW modules.  But it's still fairly long:

```
# Simplest version of pipe problem demo on Python3, stripped of everything extraneous.


import os
import time
import traceback
import subprocess       # Just for testing with the Python exe substitute.

import win32file as w32f
import win32pipe as w32p
import win32event

# Flags to indicate whether we're testing with the exe or the Python substitute, and whether we are
# opening the write-pipe (output to VCP) using os. or win32file. functions.
UseExe = 1      # If 0, use Python for everything, including Python substitute for exe. 1 = use exe.
UseOSfcns = 0   # If 1, use os.open, os.write, etc. for output pipe. 0 = use createfile/writefile 

VCPhandle = 0
VCPportNumber = -1

# Module-global read data buffer.
VCPreadData = b''
VCPstring = ""      # Incoming string from VCP.

MUhandle = 0        # Will be handle for mutex if exe is used.

# Bogus ID strings
VCPvalidIDlist = [b'Valid ID string 1', b'Valid ID string 2']



# Attempt to open port. Sets USBPIO to port handle if successful, 0 if not.
# Configures for 8 data bits, non-blocking, 0 timeout.
# USBportNumber gets set to port number.
# Returns 1 if successful, 0 if not.
def OpenPort(PortNumber):
    global VCPhandle
    
    result = 0

    try:
        VCPhandle = win32file.CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM" + str(PortNumber),
                                              win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                              0, None,
                                              win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                              0, 0)             

    except:
        #print("Could not open port - exception", PortNumber)
        VCPhandle = 0

    else:
        # Configure port for 8 data bits, 0 timeout, non blocking.

        # See if serial port is set to 7 bit size; if so, set to 8.
        USBDCB = win32file.GetCommState(VCPhandle)
        if USBDCB.ByteSize < 8:
            USBDCB.ByteSize = 8
            win32file.SetCommState(VCPhandle, USBDCB)
        
        SetTimeouts(VCPhandle)
        result = 1
            
    return result

def ReadPort(size = 1000):
    global VCPhandle
    x, indata = win32file.ReadFile(VCPhandle, size)
    return indata

# Python3 only, write to pipe.  Check data type.
def Py3WritePipe(Data):
    if type(Data) == str: DataOut = bytes(Data, "latin1")
    elif type(Data) == bytes: DataOut = Data
    elif type(Data) == int: DataOut = bytes([Data])
    if UseOSfcns: result = os.write(PipeOut, DataOut)
    else: result = w32f.WriteFile(PipeOut, DataOut)
    return result

# Empty any incoming USB VCP data.
def PY3EmptyUSB():
    global PipeIn, VCPreadData

    done = 0
    indata = ""
    while done == 0:

        # This is a bit funky.  If ReadFile is called and the pipe is
        # empty, it hangs.  So PeekNamedPipe is used to see if there is
        # data.  if there isn't, ReadFile isn't called and the loop
        # terminates.  If there is data in the pipe (return element 1
        # is available size) then empty the pipe.
        if w32p.PeekNamedPipe(PipeIn, 0)[1] > 0:
            x, indata = w32f.ReadFile(PipeIn, 1000)
        else:
            done = 1
            x = 1
            indata = ""

        if len(indata): VCPreadData += indata
        else: done = 1      # Empty read, exit.



def ClosePort():
    global VCPhandle
    try: win32file.CloseHandle(VCPhandle)
    except: pass
    VCPhandle = 0

# Shut down exe using mutex and file for Python pipe module.
def USBshutdown():
    print("USB shutdown")
    # Release mutex so exe will shut down.

    try:
        win32event.ReleaseMutex(MuHandle)  # Relese mutex to kill exe.
    except: pass

    # If using Python exe substitute, write the file to tell it to close.
    FH = open("DLPpipeShutdown.txt", "w")
    FH.write(chr(1))
    FH.close()

def CreateVCPmutex():
    global MuHandle
    # Create a mutex.  When code exits, mutex is released, so exe program
    # knows to exit as well.  Without this, the exe would never exit.
    # When exe can get this mutex, it knows Python code has exited and/or
    # released mutex.

    MuHandle = win32event.CreateMutex(None, True,"Global\\DDUSBPIOMUTEX")
    win32event.WaitForSingleObject(MuHandle, 0)

# Note: SetTimeouts MUST be called after opening comm port but before
# using comm port.  Otherwise port will hang waiting for data.
# This sets timeout so that read functions will return immediately
# if there is no data.
def SetTimeouts(commhandle, TimeoutStruct = (-1, 0, 0, 0, 0)):
    win32file.SetCommTimeouts(commhandle, TimeoutStruct)

def GetTimeouts(commhandle):
    result = win32file.GetCommTimeouts(commhandle)
    return result

# Fin VCP port by opening comm ports one at a time and
# requesting/checking ID.  Note that this does NOT use the pipes or the exe/python substitute.
# This walks through the comm ports looking for a valid VCP with a valid response.
# This code all works, finds the port, sets module-level globals for other code.
def FindVCP():
    global VCPhandle, VCPportNumber, VCPstring, USBIDFWVer

    PN = 0      # Port number to try
    ValidIDfound = 0        # Flag to indicate valid ID located.

    while PN < 32:
        # OpenPort opens and configures port for comms.
        if OpenPort(PN):
           
            # Flush anything in the incoming FIFO.
            try: VCPstring = ReadPort()
            except: pass

            # Get ID string. This was previously a function call, make it direct write for this simple case.
            result = win32file.WriteFile(VCPhandle, bytes([13])) # Send request for board ID.
            # Delay to allow plenty of time for a response.  Performance is irrelevant here as we're just trying to find the VCP).
            time.sleep(.2) 
            USBstring = ReadPort()

            # See if there is a returned string and if it's from a valid VCP HW.
            if len(USBstring) > 5:
                for ValidID in VCPvalidIDlist:
                    if ValidID in USBstring[1:]:
                        VCPportNumber = PN
                        ValidIDfound = 1

                        # Convert the ID portion of the string (minus the returned ID request opcode)
                        # to ASCII.
                        print("FindVCP ID:", USBstring[1:].decode("ascii"))

                        break       # Found the right port, exit the while loop.
                if ValidIDfound: break
            if ValidIDfound: break

                        # Normally a bunch of code goes here to configure things for specific hardware
                        # verisons/configurations. All stripped out here to simplify the example.

            # Found a valid port, but it wasn't the VCP port we want.  Close it and try the next one.
            else:
                ClosePort()
                #print("  Port opened, but no response", PN)
        #else: print("  Could not open port")

        PN += 1         # Increment port number to try.



if __name__ == "__main__":


    # This is used to signal the Python exe substitute module.
    FH = open("DLPpipeShutdown.txt", "w")
    FD = FH.write(chr(0))
    FH.close()
    
    FindVCP()

    if VCPhandle: ClosePort()


    # Now that we can see if we can find the comm port in Python, try with the exe file.
    # Just simple walk LEDs to see if we can talk to it.
    # Note that if UseExe is 0, then we use the DLL pipe substitute.  The pipes and commands
    # all work the same, it's just a matter of which one gets started and how things are
    # passed in.  The exe gets the port number from a file, the python "DLL" gets it
    # passed in as a parameter.  Shutdown uses a mutex for the exe, a value in a file for
    # the Python code.

    if UseExe:
        print("Using EXE")
        CreateVCPmutex()
        FH = open("DDUSBPort.bin", "w")
        FH.write(str(VCPportNumber))
        FH.close()

        # Tried both of these, neither works.  That is, they don't fail but the pipes don't work.
        os.startfile("USBPIOPipe.exe")
        #PipeHandle = subprocess.Popen('USBPIOPipe.exe', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

    # Use the Python DLL substitute instead 
    else:
        print("Using Python DLL substitute")
        PipeHandle = subprocess.Popen('python DLPpipe.pyc ' + str(VCPportNumber),
                                        creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

    time.sleep(.5)

    print("Creating pipeout")
    if UseOSfcns: PipeOut = os.open(r"\\.\pipe\DDUSBPIPEOUT", os.O_WRONLY)
    else:
        #PipeOut = w32f.CreateFile(r"\\.\pipe\DDUSBPIPEOUT",
        #                              w32f.GENERIC_WRITE,
        #                              w32f.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | w32f.FILE_SHARE_READ,
        #                              SecAttr,
        #                              w32f.OPEN_EXISTING,
        #                              0, 0)
        PipeOut = w32f.CreateFile(r"\\.\pipe\DDUSBPIPEOUT",
                                      w32f.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                      0,
                                      None,
                                      w32f.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                      0, 0)
    print("Creating pipein")
    #PipeIn = w32f.CreateFile(r"\\.\pipe\DDUSBPIPEIN",
    #                              w32f.GENERIC_READ,
    #                              w32f.FILE_SHARE_READ | w32f.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    #                              SecAttr,
    #                              w32f.OPEN_EXISTING,
    #                              0, 0)        
    PipeIn = w32f.CreateFile(r"\\.\pipe\DDUSBPIPEIN",
                                  w32f.GENERIC_READ,
                                  0,
                                  None,
                                  w32f.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                  0, 0)


    # Shutdown file is also indicator of when pipe handles are created.
    # Writing 1 means shut down.  Writing 2 means pipe handles created and it's OK
    # for the pipe process to execute ConnectNamedPipe on the pipe handles.
    # This is only for Python DLL substitute; the exe file uses a mutex.
    FH = open("DLPpipeShutdown.txt", "w")
    FD = FH.write(chr(2))   # 2 = pipes created, ready to go code
    FH.close()
    time.sleep(1)           # Delay a little for the file to catch up.


    # Get ID string
    Py3WritePipe(13)   # Send request for board ID.
    time.sleep(.2)
    PY3EmptyUSB()
    if len(VCPreadData): print("Using pipe:", VCPreadData.decode("ascii"))
    else: print("Using Pipe, no data received from board ID request")

    # Normally some test code would go here, but at this point I know that the
    # interface (exe or python substitute) is working or not working based on getting
    # back a valid ID string.  Note that I've tried sending commands to activate hardware
    # functions in the VCP, that do not require a response, and those don't work either.
    # So the problem is that whatever is sent doesn't go through.  In other words,
    # the problem is sending, not receiving (although receiving could be broken as well).

    # Shut down pipe in case we're using the Python exe substitute file.
    FH = open("DLPpipeShutdown.txt", "w")
    FD = FH.write(chr(1))   # 1 = shutdown code.
    FH.close()

    # If we were using the pipe exe, close the mutex so the exe closes.
    if UseExe:
        # Release mutex so EXE will shut down.
        try:
            print("Closing mutex")
            time.sleep(1)
            win32event.ReleaseMutex(MuHandle)  # Relese mutex to kill exe.
            win32event.ReleaseMutex(MuHandle)  # Relese mutex to kill exe.
        except: pass
        time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: If you do have a [mcve], please share it. Any change in roughly *10 years* that might potentially affect this is... a huge answer space.

Comment: Well, alright, here it is.  I created a simple test program for debugging this, which eliminates all the other HW and SW components. It does demonstrate the problem, although I doubt it will be useful in answering the question.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it.  It was a mistake in the conversion to Python 3; I would have expected it to throw an exception, but it didn't.  So I kept thinking the pipes weren't working.